# MySQL Stored Procedure select not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have the following stored procedure in a MySQL db.  It doesn't return anything when I run it from my PHP code(Which I know is correct because it works for all of my other stored procedures).  When I log into phpmyadmin and execute the stored procedure from the "Routines" page it works just fine.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
DELIMITER //

drop procedure if exists spGetTeam //

CREATE PROCEDURE spGetTeam(IN tid INT)
BEGIN
   SELECT team_id, team_name FROM teams WHERE team_id = tid;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm calling the sp from my php like so:

```
$sql = 'CALL spGetTeam(2)';
```

The sp is called with the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    //handle return 
}
```

Comment: Can you post how you are calling

Comment: It's got to be your calling code. Maybe it's the parameter. You should better show your relevant php too.

Comment: I think you need an OUT parameter to your stored proc

Comment: I could use an OUT parameter but I haven't had to do that for any other stored procedures that are working.  Why is this so different?

Comment: Perhaps there is no team with team_id 2?

Comment: Like I said this runs fine through phpmyadmin..  There is definitely a team with a team_id of 2.

Comment: And exactly how do you execute this sql statement?

Comment: Added execution of sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

This started working the next day.  Not sure what happened.  No code was changed.  If I ever figure it out I will update the answer.

Comment: Did you lack execute permissions initially? Is that what changed?